# Switching back to English from Chinese adds line break

Tags: ios, localization

I implemented Localisation in my app but I am facing complication in UIButton. When I switch back to English from Chinese it looks something like this:

[image]

I added width and height to that particular button but it don't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give button Width By Multiplier [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c35SJ.png)

[image]